# 360 image appears blurry in web app developed in a-frame for oculus go. how to fix it?

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus, oculusgo

I want to build a 360 image gallery in a-frame for oculus go. I tried one of the examples in the a-frame website for 360 image gallery but when i put my 360 images in it, the image is blurry. How to fix it?